# How to check call count in HTTPX library

Tags: python, unit-testing, httpx

Using requests_mock I can check if it was called with call_count attribute like in the example below:

```
def test_foo(
    self,
    response,
    mock_service,
):
    assert mock_service.call_count == 1
```

But now I'm using httpx library. How I can check the same in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pytest-httpx](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-httpx/) to mock httpx. Then you will be able to check every request that was issued. Or simply check the number of issued requests via:

```
def test_nb_queries(httpx_mock):
    assert len(httpx_mock.get_requests()) == 2
```

And if there is a single request expected, you can even do:

```
def test_single_query(httpx_mock):
    assert httpx_mock.get_request()
```